# How to disable last page button in primeNG datatable?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to disable last page button in the `primeNG` datatable div.
The paginator is in the `p-datatable` tag.

code :

```
  <div class="ui-g-12">
      <p-dataTable [value]="bossDataTable" resizableColumns="true" columnResizeMode="expand" [lazy]="true" [rows]="15" [paginator]="true"
      [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[15,20,25,30,40,50]" (onLazyLoad)="getBossDataTable($event)" >

         <!--some columns here -->
          <p-footer><span><label i18n>Total:</label> {{totalRecords}}</span></p-footer>
      </p-dataTable>
```

According to doc:
`https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator`

I got last page style here:
`ui-paginator-last`

How can I disable the last page button?Hide it or disable it is OK.

Now the paginator looks like :
`|< < 1 2 3 4 5 > >|`

Comment: Please use the correct tags. Primefaces = jsf, primeng = angular. So your question has nothing to do with primefaces.

Comment: Sorry sir,I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide the last page button like this:

```
.ui-paginator > .ui-paginator-last {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Since `.ui-paginator-last` is an anchor tag you can simulate it being disabled by doing this:

```
.ui-paginator > .ui-paginator-last {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
}
```

If you want the pagination to be unique you can add it to the footer of the DataTable and give it a unique `styleClass`:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" (change)="onDataTableChange($event)"
    styleClass="hidden-last"
    resizableColumns="true" [reorderableColumns]="true">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" 
    [header]="col.header"></p-column>
  <p-footer><p-paginator styleClass="paginator1"></p-paginator></p-footer>
</p-dataTable>
```

Then you'll have to do the same thing, but use the class name you gave the paginator:

```
.paginator1 > .ui-paginator-last {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: gray;
}
```

or:

```
.paginator1 > .ui-paginator-last {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Here's a plnkr demonstrating this approach (two tables, one last button disabled):
[Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/E6eJ03AsfXBpuy6WiWjv?p=preview)

Comment: Where shall I put these code ?Component CSS?It doesn't work for me.I don't want to disable / hide all last page button.I just want to disable/hide at this page.

Comment: I've updated answer now. I also added a Plunker demo

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'll try.